# Search SQL Server Execution Plan by cost in SSMS

Tags: ssms, execution-plan

I was given a large Execution plan and I'm trying to find the nodes connected to high costs. SSMS offers a search util, however, I did not find the option that searches for the cost value in percent.
Given my image below, how do I search for a node causing 21 percent of the cost? The second input allows to select `equals` and `contains`. Is it possible to search for operations that cost more than 15 %?

[image: SSMS ExecutionPlan search]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A much better option would be to use [SentryOne's Free Plan explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer). It is 1000% better than SSMS.

You can also have it configured to install it as SSMS addin and then when you right click any plan, it will allow you to open in Plan explorer.

Comment: I had hoped for an SSMS solution. Thanks for the tipp to use the alternative tool.